# It's very confusing.. I was creating .net core web application and can see .NetFramework with .NetCore support

Tags: asp.net-core

I was creating .net core web application and can see .NetFramework with .NetCore support. But I didn't choose .Net Standard. I don't understand. Please see the image [asp.net core web application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYaEE.png)

Comment: Hey and welcome. I'm not sure what the problem is. The name of the framework is still dotnet (thus dotnet framework). The latest releases are either dotnet core or dotnet 5. So you are creating a dotnet framework solution and you can select which version of the asp.net core framework you will use. The asp.net core framework is a specific set of services built on top op the dotnet core framework to easily create/serve web pages or api endpoints. What is your specific problem?

Comment: Thanks Ken.As you see the image,my confusion is:on the left dropdown I selected .Net Framework and on the right hand dropdown ASP.NET Core 1.0 and so on are available. I am used to of creating pure .Net Framework application or pure .Net Core Application. Here i can see .Net Framework on left and .Net core on right. This I don't understand. This is the way I have created the application: New Project-> Asp.Net Core application (c#) -> (name and location) => then the dialog apppear. I could have gone selecting .Net Core in the left side drop down. But when I choose .Net Framwork, I got confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, before .net core 3.0, asp.net core is support on .net framework. This is the reason why you could create .net core 2.1 on the .net framework.

But after 3.0, asp.net core not support .net framework. You could only create it on .net core framework.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx) and this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3753).

Comment: Thanks Brando. Even if I have chosen New Project-> Asp.Net Core application (c#), why they gave me the option to choose between 2 options .Net Framwork and .Net core. And for the sake of curiosity when I choose .Net Framework from the left dropdown the application got created with <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework> and it has a startup class as well. So its a ASP.Net Core app which got created.

Comment: As I says, previous .net core version could run on the .net framework. After 3.0 them you couldn't start creating the .net core application on .net farmework. You could find the version of the .net core is just before 2.2 in VS.

Comment: If you feel my reply has helped you. Please mark it as answer, it will help other folks who faces the same issue could find the answer more easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is Microsoft naming at work here.  There are two dotnet frameworks: the "full" framework, which you selected, and the dotnet core framework.

Before dotnet core and all it's optimized, multiplatform goodness, there was the dotnet framework (refered to as the legacy or full framework). This is the predecessor of dotnet core. This full framework runs only on Windows and the computer it runs on needs the dotnet framework runtime.

Do not worry, the "full" in full framework comes from the transition period between the old dotnet framework and dotnet core. When dotnet core was version 1.0, it did not have all the functionality of today. So some developers called it the full framework (which had everything you needed to run your application) and the newer dotnet core framework which had only the basics.

You can see if you are running the legacy framework if there is the `<TargetFramework>netXXX</TargetFramework>` present in your solution/project file. The lastest version of the full dotnet framework is 4.8 (net48).

After that it switched to dotnet core 1.0 - 3.1. I'm not entirely sure how that's referenced in the solution/project files.

As a last remark, Microsoft had a great naming idea: the next version of dotnet core is named dotnet 5. They want to get back to the original name with this next version. Do keep in mind that you cannot easily upgrade from dotnet 4.X to dotnet 5. The day to day code looks very much alike, but the underlying engine is completely rewritten.